# Change links type from .php?id= to html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, httpd.conf

I have a file hosting and sharing PHP script, which uses the basic type of links, when a file has been uploaded, the basic link of the file will be :
http://example.com/do.php?id=1

Noting that the (1) is the file ID.

Now the script has a feature to enable the mod rewrite with HTML links type.. when Activate it .. the link above will be like this:
http://example.com/download1.html

Now, the htaccess file need to be edited to change the links to another shape.. So what I want to do is to make the above link looks like:
http://example.com/filename_FileID.html
or
http://example.com/FileID.html
or
http://example.com/filename_RandomCharectars&numbers.html

and I don't know how to do it .. Please help me editing my htaccess..

Here is the currect htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^download([0-9]*).html$ do.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^downloadf-(.*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$ do.php?filename=$1&x=$2
RewriteRule ^down-([0-9]*).html$ do.php?down=$1
RewriteRule ^downf-(.*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$ do.php?downf=$1&x=$2
RewriteRule ^downex-([0-9]*).html$ do.php?down=$1
RewriteRule ^downexf-(.*)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$ do.php?downexf=$1&x=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For http://example.com/FileID.html  (I'm assuming "FileID" is going to be a numeric value)

The rule is

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)\.html$ do.php?id=$1
```

For http://example.com/filename_FileID.html 
The rule is

```
RewriteRule ^filename_([0-9]*)\.html$ do.php?id=$1
```

For http://example.com/filename_RandomCharectars&numbers.html
The rule is

```
RewriteRule ^filename_(.*)\.html$ do.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. But I wanted $filename instead of filename_ ... it will be automatically replaced by original filename.. and by the way, How many random characters will be generated in the rule : RewriteRule ^filename_([a-zA-Z0-9]*).html$ do.php?id=$1

Comment: I have edited the last rule for better results, to handle any character any number of times. I don't understand this part of your comment "But I wanted $filename instead of filename_". Can you clarify?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100577/htaccess-editing-rewrite-links-to-another-type