# htaccess editing ( rewrite links to another type )

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I've a file sharing script, When I upload a file, the download link of the file is showing as this :
http://www.example.net/file?id=fileID

Noting that the ( file?id=fileID ) is given by a functions php file .. while the original shape of links : download.php?id=fileID.

Now when I browse the link http://www.example.net/file?id=fileID ... I get Not found .. and the htaccess has the following :

```
RewriteRule ^file([0-9]*)?id=$ download.php?id=$1
```

and it still not found..
So I want to Rewrite the original links to work when I browse the link: 
http://www.example.net/file?id=fileID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
RewriteRule ^file/? download.php [QSA]
```

I used the QSA flag because it retains the query string and passes it on to the new URL. By default, RewriteRule will discard the query string.

Edit:
Based on your comment, use this rule to achieve what you want.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)img(.*)$
RewriteRule ^download.php/? img.php?%1id%2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you ..This will only work on the mentioned link type .. I mean now it worked as  http://www.example.net/file?id=fileID ....
But, there is an images links where they stopped working and I want to Rewrite them too ..
Original:  http://www.example.net/download.php?img=ID
Need Rewrite it as: http://www.example.net/img?id=ID

Comment: Thanks for the edit, But it didn't solve it.. I still get Not found when I Browse http://www.example.net/img?id=ID ... Note: I have also tried to edit your code to become: 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)img(.*)$
RewriteRule ^do.php/? img?%1id%2 [QSA]
-------------------
it still give not found. Not that images should be called through download.php to count the downloads and visits.. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: RewriteRule ^img/?([0-9]*)$ download.php?img=%1 [QSA]
This Code works partially.. I mean when I browse :
http://www.example.net/img?id=ID
It calls the link:
http://www.example.net/download.php?id=ID
What I want is to change the call .. so it can call this:
http://www.example.net/img?img=ID

Comment: Here, try this
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)id(.*)$`
`RewriteRule ^img/?([0-9]*)$ download.php?%1img%2 [QSA]`

If you're still having problems, we may have to go back to the top and provide more details about what you're trying to achieve on a broader scale.

Comment: Thank you very much... The problem solved with the code that you sent in your last comment.. But with a little change, I've removed the [QSA] flag so now the URL's are working with the new type..